# what is wrong in networkx installation

Tags: python, networkx

This is my first time do programming; i have a project that requires netwok analysis.
I downloaded networkx 1.6 and tried out the blockmodel, i got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\Research Project\python\blockmodel.py", line 52, in <module>
    G=nx.read_edgelist("hartford_drug.edgelist")
  File "<string>", line 2, in read_edgelist
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\networkx\utils\decorators.py", line 173, in _open_file
    fh = _dispatch_dict[ext](path, mode=mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hartford_drug.edgelist'
```

What is wrong? especially i run both the zip file and egg file
grateful for any urgent help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the data file hartford_drug.edgelist which you can get from here:http://networkx.lanl.gov/hg/networkx/raw-file/bec267f40c83/examples/algorithms/hartford_drug.edgelist